# How to get PDF receipt for completed Uber journey

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to get the PDF receipt for the Uber journey I have completed. There doesn't seem to be a specific API for the same. How can I retrieve that data?

Comment: In your application click "send me receipt" and you'll receive it to email.

Comment: If you need the PDF so you can attach it as a receipt to an expense report, I always just go to `Print` the page/email, and then `Preview in PDF Viewer`, and then save/export the email as a PDF. The steps/tools involved will be different depending on your browser, OS and PDF reader, but it should get you through the door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to get a PDF receipt via the API.